# Pointer increment answer not understood

Tags: c++, pointers

I have been trying for such code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int t=1;
    cout<<t<<" ";
    int *b = new int(t);
    cout<<*b++<<" ";
    cout <<*b<<" ";
    cout<<t<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

It is giving me output as 1 1 0 1. I cant understand 0 in the output. Please explain me why this is happening ?

Comment: Short answer: undefined behavior. What is `b` pointing at after you increment it?

Comment: You're thinking `(*b)++`, but the language is doing `*(b++)`.

Comment: Read the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). In general, don't try to learn C++ based on guessing, it's too weird for that.

Answer (score 5):

The precedence of the `++` operator is higher than that of the `*` operator in this case. You are thus incrementing the pointer `b` itself rather than the memory being pointed to (which is presumably your intention).

To get the behaviour you want:

```
cout<<(*b)++<<" ";
```

Comment: The OP must add parenthesis to remove ambiguities.

Comment: I know how to do that..* and ++ both have same precedence but resolved in right to left...actually I want to know why in case of undefined it is printing 0.

Comment: You're incrementing a pointer beyond its allocated region, then dereferencing, which is undefined behaviour. It happens to output a 0 because the memory beyond happens to contain a 0.

Answer (score 4):

After the line

```
cout << *b++ << " ";
```

`b` points to memory beyond what was allocated.

The line after that,

```
cout << *b << " ";
```

dereferences memory beyond valid limits.  Hence, it is cause for undefined behavior.